# How do I setup 301 redirects in Google Apps site?

Tags: url-rewriting, 301-redirect, google-workspace

I have just moved a website from a shared host to a Google Apps site.

Is there a way I can setup 301 redirects on my Google Apps site so that old links (with a different URL) can be 301 redirected to the new location on the new site?

Answer (score 2):

This would seem to be informative: [301 Redirect codes for google apps](https://sites.google.com/a/aguy.us/aguy-us-google-apps-premier/cloud-email/301-redirect-codes)

Comment: unfortunately, I already know about 301 redirects, and how to code them, however I am seeking a way to manage this within Google Sites - which does not permit javascript nor access to directly manipulate the header HTML (at least I don't think they do - that might be the answer by george)

Comment: You'd need a meta forward - this is html and, though w3c invalid you can put this anywhere in the page and it will work. http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/f/what-is-a-meta-redirect.htm

Comment: I understand meta forwards, however *where* do I put these in my Google Apps site?  I can't write code into the HTML <head> section of a page in google apps

Comment: @arrocharJames it should work anywhere in the body

Comment: thanks, I will try that - however I would still have to create a page for every "old" page to redirect to the new.  However, I still would prefer a server-level 301 redirect - and I would think that Google would want their users doing that as well... fix up the indexes, and what not.

Comment: Well, you could meta redirect all users to a single page and have that page direct them over with the proper status code?

Comment: sorry to ask you to do work, but I'd love it if you would post your thoughts as an answer, as this comment thread is completely wrong for the original answer post above, which has the issue entirely backwards (and you do not - so i can't vote this up, but I would certainly vote your info up).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Google Sites, but a bit of searching turned up [this forum post](http://virtualmechanics.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/1246038591/m/5897072016#post_6547073016), where a user named "larryd" writes:

> "I wasn't familiar with Google sites when I made my post, so my 2 cents isn't worth much.
>
> However, after logging in and creating a test Google site, I've found that if you log into your Google site and Edit your page, you can use the Insert->More gadgets menu option to open the gadget window. In the search box, enter *url redirect* and click the search button. A list of gadgets will appear; scroll to find the gadget named "Url Redirector" and click it. In the next window, click the "Select" button.
>
> On your web page, you should now see a Google Gadget box with the "Url Redirector" loaded. Click the Properties link at the bottom. In the Setup Gadget window, enter the URL of your new site in the PageTo box and set the Timeout to what you want.
>
> The PageTo entry must be the full URL, including the http:// prefix. If you do not enter a complete URL, your visitors will get a 404 error. If you want an immediate redirection, the Timeout setting should be 0, but this may make your Google web page inaccessible for editing in the future as entering the Google site will cause an immediate re-direct and may not give you enough time to hit the Edit button.
>
> You will need to add this gadget to every web page on your Google site."

Note that these instructions are for redirecting from Google Sites to an external site, but, assuming that they work at all, I see no reason why they wouldn't work for redirects from one Google Sites page to another, too.  That said, **I have not tested these instructions.**  Use at your own risk.

**Edit:** Searching for [*Google Sites "URL redirect"*](http://www.google.com/search?q=Google+Sites+%22URL+redirect%22) also turned up [these instruction](http://www.bricecenter.com/how-to-reviews/google-sites/url-redirect), complete with screenshots.  However, their [demo page](http://www.bricecenter.com/how-to-reviews/computers/hardware/asus-m4a89gtd-pro-usb3-realtek-alc892-optical-audio-sound-problems) doesn't seem to be working for me. :-(

Comment: That URL Redirector gadget is using javascript to redirect, which is bad in my opinion. It won't help with search engines or with users that don't use javascript.

Comment: Actually, some search engines (including Google) do run JavaScript nowadays, so it may work with them. Still, you're right that a JS redirect is very much a suboptimal solution; however, as far as I know it's the best you can do with Google Sites.